# Leaflet to select a location

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to use Leaflet to have the user input lat long information. Should I be creating and deleting markers and calculating the lat-long of each click/touch by myself or is there a cleaner way for the user to be able to select a location?

Answer (score 4):

Leaflet MouseEvent's already contain [latlng](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events-latlng) information. From there you should be able to add and remove markers during each click event.

```
var marker;
map.on('click', function(e) {
    if(marker)
        map.removeLayer(marker);
    console.log(e.latlng); // e is an event object (MouseEvent in this case)
    marker = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
});
```